# Integrating a $2$ form on $\mathbb C \mathbb P^1$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Assume we have the $2$-form $\omega = \frac 1 {2 \pi i} \frac {dz \wedge d\overline z}{(1 + z \overline z)^2}$ given on $U = \{[1:z] : z \in \mathbb C \} \subset \mathbb C \mathbb P^1$, where $z: U \to \mathbb C$ is the map $[1:z] \mapsto z$.

How can I integrate this form, i.e. what is $\int_U \omega$ ?

Comment: $\int_U \omega$ is just a complicated way to write $$\int_{\mathbb{C}} \frac{dz\wedge d\overline{z}}{(1+ \lvert z\rvert^2)^2}.$$ It's probably easiest to evaluate in polar coordinates.

Comment: I am not sure what this expression means when integrating over $\mathbb C$. As definition I have read that we should compute the pullbackform on $\mathbb C$, i.e. $(z^{-1})^*(\omega)$ and then integrate the resulting function $f$ such that the pullback is given by $f(z) dz$. Is that right ?

Comment: The pull-back of a $k$-form is a $k$-form, so you don't get $f(z)\,dz$, which is a $1$-form, but $f(z)\, dz\wedge d\overline{z}$, which is a $2$-form. Write $dz \wedge d\overline{z}$ in terms of $dx$ and $dy$ if that looks more familiar, $dz \wedge d\overline{z} = (dx + idy)\wedge (dx - idy) = -2i dx \wedge dy$. So you get to calculate $$-2i \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx\,dy.$$

Comment: Ok that makes it clear. I did not think about splitting in real and imaginary parts.